# How can I force LESS (css) to recognize a variable?

Tags: css, less

I have a few images on my site that will change over time. To be sure the CSS forces updates when I make changes, I have appended a query variable with a version string to them:

```
#branding{ background: url(../img/branding.jpg?v2); }
```

I'd like to be able to do this with LESS so I don't have to change all of the image references:

```
@mediaVersion: 101;
#branding{ background: url(../img/branding.jpg?v@mediaVersion); }
```

However Less.app can not recognize the variable `@mediaVersion` in that string and leaves it as written. I tried wrapping it in `{@mediaVersion}` and also `(@mediaVersion)` but those cause errors when compiling. I tried adding a semi colon after it.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Question: What do you do if the browser caches the CSS file?

Comment: `link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css?v2"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@mediaVersion: 101;
#branding{ background: url("../img/branding.jpg?v@{mediaVersion}"); }
```

The section "String interpolation" at http://lesscss.org/#-variables shows that this should work.

Comment: perfect! not for others: i had to use both the `{}` AS WELL AS wrapping the inner contents of `url()` with the double quotes, just as you suggested.

Comment: How could you do this using variable math? E.g. @mobile: ~"(max-width: @{main} - 1)"; where I need the - 1 to work?